# Charts.js How to add a link when you click a barchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have read a few answers already and none of them worked for me probably because I am a noob.
If someone has some time to help me out by telling me how to add a dynamic link when I click one of the bars in my bar chart.
I am using the newest charts.js (2+).  I also have a variable that is a list of values => process_net_benefit eg (345,231,123,423,123,123)

Here is the code of my bar chart

> ```
> > new Chart(document.getElementById("net-benefit"), {
> >     type: 'bar',
> >     data: {
> >       labels: {{ process_net_benefit_name|safe }},
> >       click: onClick,
> >       datasets: [{
> >                label: 'Process Saving',
> >                data: {{ process_net_benefit|safe }},
> >                backgroundColor: "#4e73df",
> >                hoverBackgroundColor: "#2e59d9",
> >                borderColor: "#4e73df",
> >                borderWidth: 1
> >            }]
> >     },
> >     options: {
> >        legend: {
> >             display: false
> >          },
> >         scales: {
> >           yAxes: [
> >                 { 
> >                   ticks: {
> >                         callback: function(label, index, labels) {
> >                             return label/1000+'k';
> >                         }
> >                     },
> >                     scaleLabel: {
> >                         display: true,
> >                         labelString: '1k = 1000 USD'
> >                     }
> >                 }
> >             ],
> >           xAxes: [{
> >             stacked: true,
> >             ticks: {
> >               beginAtZero: true
> >             }
> >           }]
> >       
> >         },
> >               tooltips: {
> >                 titleMarginBottom: 10,
> >                 titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
> >                 titleFontSize: 14,
> >                 backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
> >                 bodyFontColor: "#858796",
> >                 borderColor: '#dddfeb',
> >                 borderWidth: 1,
> >                 xPadding: 15,
> >                 yPadding: 15,
> >                 displayColors: false,
> >                 caretPadding: 10,
> >                 callbacks: {
> >                   label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
> >                       var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
> >                       return datasetLabel + ': $' + (tooltipItem.yLabel);
> >                       }
> >                   }
> >             },
> >       }    });
> ```

I would like to click on the bar and open a link. The link should be dynamic and take you to the detail page for that bar. Please let me know if you need more info, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick function on the option object.

```
const options = {
  onClick(event, activeElements) {
    // id of your clicked element
    console.log(activeElements.pop()._index);
  },
}
```